# Destroy cookies in rails, facebook connect, facebooker plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, cookies, session

So I have sort of a weird situation going on.  I am using the Facebooker plugin for rails where I want users to be able to login and logout with their facebook profiles.  However, once users logout, if I refresh the page, it logs them back in.  This is only when users log in with facebook connect.

I think the problem is that a rogue cookie is just re-instantiating the session and thus my best guess is to manually destroy the cookies but to be honest I'm not entirely sure of how to do this.  I printed out my cookie list (from request.cookies) both before and after I click logout.  After logout is clicked, I still have this cookie lingering...but don't know how to delete it.

fbsetting_0b78c8f2c95ce671470bdcb1c19e5070  {"connectState":1,"oneLineStorySetting":1,"shortStorySetting":1,"inFacebook":false}

After playing around with it a little more, that cookie isn't even there...but upon refreshing the page I am logged in again.

I'm doing this all on localhost...not sure if that should cause a problem or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destroying local cookies isn't enough to terminate a Facebook Connect session.  The connect JS library will recreate destroyed cookies as long as you still have an active session on the facebook.com domain -- and those cookies are inaccessible to you.

All log-outs must be handled by calling the logout function in the connect library.

e.g.,

```
<script>$H.fbconnect.logout();</script>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work (at least in facebooker).  It logs you out of facebook, but the app cookie persists.  If you log back into facebook, then the app thinks you're connected again.

Comment: You'll need to trigger a local logout as well, then. That's actually what I do in the app I run -- the facebook logout runs, and then immediately triggers our normal logout process, like: $H.fbconnect.logout('/my_logout_script.php');

Answer (score 6):

This is what I have in users controller

```
  def logout_facebook
    clear_facebook_session_information
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

and this is how it is triggered

```
<%= fb_logout_link("Logout out", "#{root_url}users/logout_facebook")%>
```

This is how I got it to remove the cookies on the local side.

Note: don't forget to add a route to the logout_facebook method in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie, you need to set the cookie again with an expiration date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

a million thanks for the clean and full-proof solution to such a frazzled functionality. I've been literally going Blank over last 2 weeks since I came across the fact true to I believe almost all NEW-facebooker users, "facebook connect logging out completely". Or maybe just it was just a lack of documentation or some code excerpt I wasn't able to find till date in facebooker cover docs.

Anyway away from all that, moving to the solution which made me achieve it... Following to @James B method above.

---

Obviously I am assuming you all have read facebooker installation, configuration & usage instructions http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker.
I also have  used a plugin "authlogic_facebook_connect" which you can find at github.com page of kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect.

Now I assume you already configured your application to work with facebook connect by using fb_login_button or authlogic_facebook_login_button. Clicking it you'd see a popup to log yourself into both your facebook account and into the local account of your app. Once you login you'd be getting a facebook_session to handle saving a new user in your DB (only if you wish to).

By default you'd not be getting birthday and email address of users in the facebook_session as response from facebook. To get them you need something like this in your initialization javascript in the body tag of the rhtml page...

```
<%= fb_connect_javascript_tag %>   <%=
init_fb_connect "XFBML",{
:app_settings=>" {
permsToRequestOnConnect :
'email,user_birthday' }"} %>
<%= authlogic_facebook_login_button %>
```

Now finally what I did for getting logged out of both Facebook and my site.

1. Inside the header of your application or wherever the LOGIN, LOGOUT, loggedin users's name etc will display...

   :delete
   %>

The two logout buttons are for different kind of users.. a. who registered directly on your site, b. who registerd to your site via facebook

2. Route for logout_both in routes.rb

> map.connect "/logout_both",
>   :controller=>"users",
>   :action=>"logout_both"

3. The action for logout_both inside users_controller.rb

   def logout_both
       current_user_session.destroy
       #clear_facebook_session_information
       flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"
       redirect_to root_path  end #End of method logout_both
4. You need to make sure that there are no filters defined in the controller which could restrict logout_both action to be executed without a session.
5. Oh yes and if you're wondering why that "clear_facebook_session_information" is commented in the action. Then don't worry, you're already logged out of facebook before entering this action, this line is no longer needed. Boss we're using "fb_logout_link" which first logs you out and then redirects you to this new action.

Well, that's about it. If this doesn't do it........ get your hands dirty like I am doing.. dig in.. solve it yourself. Facebooker is deep but has a definite END!!!

Again many thanks to mangino & kalasjocke for making facebook connect almost no painful for rails.

---

One clarification people... in my Answer above.. There is a hick, which is.. After logout, if you refresh the page.. it would again show you logged in on your site.. however you're successfully logged out of Facebook. 
I was wrong, ONE BIG CLARIFICATION...... As a matter of fact you DO NEED THESE TWO LINES IN YOUR "logout_both" action

```
def logout_both <br/>
      current_user_session.destroy<br/>
      clear_facebook_session_information  #MANDATORY TO COMPLETELY CLEAR COOKIES<br/>
      reset_session  # TO BE 100% sure you can use it optionally<br/>
      flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"<br/>
      redirect_to root_path   <br/>
end
```